# UWP write List<T> to a File

Tags: c#, list, uwp

I'm trying to write a file in an UWP app that includes the  items in a List of objects.

I write the file, but it only includes the first line.

Here is my code:

```
List<OPSDATA> SortedList = origList.OrderBy(o => o.OPS).ToList();

StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("data.txt");

if (file != null)
{

    foreach (var item in SortedList)
    {
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", item.OPS, item.LEAGUE, item.RPG));
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

> 0.858,0,5.4

SortedList has 60 elements.

`

Comment: Why call `ToList()` at all?

Comment: "but it only includes the first line" - seem to be a problem. Should be the last one as you are overwriting content and not appending.

Comment: Instead of WriteTextAsync perhaps you want AppendTextAsync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use [FileIO.WriteLinesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileio.writelinesasync)?

```
var sortedLines = origList.OrderBy(o => o.OPS)
                          .Select(i => $"{i.OPS},{i.LEAGUE},{i.RPG}");

StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("data.txt");

if (file != null)
{
    await FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(file, sortedLines);
}
```